# Model a given problem using Multiobjective and Goal programming.

Tags: optimization

An electronics manufacturing company sets up security alarms for the market
ersidential security. It produces three systems: The **Guard Dog**, The **Home Guard** and the top of the line Terminator III. The assembly of the Guard Dog takes 1.5 hours per unit. The Home Guard requires two hours of assembly, and the **Terminator III** requires 2.5 hours for assembly. The number of hours available for production is 240. The profitability of the Guard Dog it's US\$ 320, Home Guard it's US\$ 320 It's from Terminator III it's US\$ 350. The sales team predicted that next week's sales will be 60 units of each product. Management has determined several goals that are equally important to the company:

1. Produce 60 units of each product;
2. Use all available assembly hours;
3. Generate profits from at least US\$ 3.600.

Assess the problem with a multi-objective, linear model.
Formulate and solve the goal programming problem.

I am unable to mount the objective function.
Sorry for the writing, because it is not my mother tongue.

Comment: I would post a picture of the table I made, but because it is new here the site does not allow it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As restrições são suas Metas, agora você tem que a plicar os pesos para encontrar as funções objetivas.